# Indexer "updated" column not updated?

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-2.1, indexing

I noticed that the "updated" column for indexers only changes, when I run the indexers manually from the command line. It seems like everything is up to date (i.e. I see changes reflected in the frontend)

They are set to "update on save". When I change the mode to "update by schedule", the date changes as expected.

What could be the reason? Is this the normal behavior in Magento 2.1?

Comment: Good question, personally I just add an extra cron job.

Comment: Maybe this date is updated only when the full reindex is trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class ***Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\State*** serves for keeping index state, and column ***updated*** is modified with this piece of code.

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    $this->setUpdated(time());
    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

It will be triggered on (almost) every ***save()*** call. It happens in ***Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer*** within ***reindexAll()***, ***reindexRow()***, ***reindexList()*** methods.

When `$this->getState()->save()` is called from one of those three methods, then save() method from ***\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb*** will be called:

```
public function save(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object)
{    
    ...
    try {
    if (!$this->isModified($object)) {
        $this->processNotModifiedSave($object);
        $this->commit();
        $object->setHasDataChanges(false);
        return $this;
    }
    $object->validateBeforeSave();
    $object->beforeSave();
    ...
```

What is "the issue" here?

Well, if you call `$this->getState()->save()` (as it's done in ***reindexRow()*** and ***reindexList()***), then because of `if (!$this->isModified($object))` - ***beforeSave()*** will never be triggerred. It further means that new updated time will not be set.

In case you call full reindex from command line, it will execute ***reindexAll()***. The difference here is that there is a piece of code which sets status ***STATUS_WORKING***:

```
public function reindexAll()
{
    if ($this->getState()->getStatus() != StateInterface::STATUS_WORKING) {
        $state = $this->getState();
        $state->setStatus(StateInterface::STATUS_WORKING);
        $state->save();
        ...
```

Since here data is changed, then beforeSave() will be triggered, and new ***updated*** time will be set.

The real question at the end is:
`Is it a bug or a feature?`